# ZXing completely included, but camera rotated

Tags: android, include, frame, qr-code, zxing

i have included completely the zxing in my app,to make it stand-alone.
it works, but the camera is rotated (i think 90 counterclockwise), and it has a strange padding aroud.
my java:

```
package it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity;

public class Lettore extends CaptureActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lettore);
}
@Override 
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Scanned code " +     rawResult.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
}
```

and my xml (which take the activity of zxing like include):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"     android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/head" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="250dip">
    <include layout="@layout/capture" android:toDegrees="90" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the padding is this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16047047/Untitled-1.jpg

can someone post a solution?

thanks a lot

Comment: Remove it from your app and integrate with Intents. It is the way the system was meant to be used. And it will result in far fewer headaches for you, I promise.

Comment: but i can't... it must appear in my views, not with a new intent (which go in a new views in fullscreen).
if i can integrate an intent in my views it's ok but i don't know how.
in other word: the things must remain like my screen: see that there's an image below? and that the camera is integrated?

Comment: Why "must" it appear in your own Views? The people who created BarcodeScanner did a wonderful job. And have provided you with a dead simple way to integrate it with your own app. You are "swimming up stream" by trying to copy/paste their source into your app. It will cause more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: because i must do it. my client want it. and in the iphone app, the coder did it, and i did not copy the source, i've integrated it via library in ecplipse

Comment: there's no a way to throw an intent inside my view? i think there's must be a way...

Comment: No there is no way, the intent is starting a different Activity specifically it is starting the CaptureActivity which is inside the BarcodeScanner application, not your own.

Comment: You should take a look at the original project's Manifest file and determine the orientation for that scanner activity.

Answer (score 2):

It's 90 degree rotated because Zxing is designed for only landscape mood..And I thin your application is working in portrait mood.

you can try this in `ConfigurationManager.java`

```
void setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting preview size: " + cameraResolution);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    parameters.setRotation(90);
    if (camera != null)
        try {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError ex) {
        }
    setFlash(parameters);
    setZoom(parameters);
    // setSharpness(parameters);
    setSharpness(parameters);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

}
```

NOTE: But it is not the way to include their code in your project. You need to use it through Intents.

Comment: That's correct, you need to implement your own portrait-mode layouts as the app is not portrait-mode. You can't and shouldn't copy the project UI. `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` is essentially the line that is needed, but it does get more complex than that when you consider that some cameras are not mounted at 90 degrees, and there are front cameras for which it's flipped over.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply change the manifest file to have only landscape mode.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:label="ZXing"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Comment: This is useful. I set the CatureActivity orientation to landscape in my manifest and it worked fine.